# Loading Java heap dump back into memory?

Tags: java, serialization, heap-dump

**Is there a way to dump (a part of) the Java heap and the load it back into memory?** What I have in mind is not necessarily to dump the whole heap, but rather to save a select but large number of objects, which are the result of a costly parsing method, to a binary image and then load them back on demand.

Of course I could serialize the objects in a binary format (which would need to be defined), but my question is whether it's possible to dump the objects in "raw form", if that makes sense, using standard tools.

Comment: "rare form"? *Raw* form?

Comment: No, not possible. Standard tools are usually for standard tasks, and this is certainly not one of them. Serializing to a binary representation is what you want here. Java can do it natively with just a marker interface.

Comment: As the previous comment says - it is not possible. The best practice would be serialization and even better approach would be to use commonly recognized formats (JSON is still very popular) to save the state of your application.

Comment: Serializing to a *non-binary* format like JSON is exactly what I'm trying to avoid, for otherwise there would be absolutely no point in doing so, as the thing to be saved is the result of a deserialization (parsing) already. I am trying to avoid the cost of parsing.

Comment: I guess that the comment of @Michael, suggesting Java own binary serialization construct, is actually what I'm looking for in my case. If you formulate this as an answer, Michael, I can accept it.

Comment: Depending on what you’re doing, a [memory-mapped file](https://www.baeldung.com/java-mapped-byte-buffer) might be suitable.

Comment: Thanks @TimMoore for that suggestion, that might be useful in other circumstances. But here the problem lies not in repeatedly reading the same file but rather in the cost of parsing. The standard serialization algorithm of ObjectOutputStream seems to be what solves my problem.